# How to create context menu with two different option sets?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I need to create two context menus in my WPF application. On the picture below you can see, that the left menu contains **Create** and **Delete**. This should be only or Directories. The right picture is for files. Can anyone help me how I should do this?

I have already done it like on the right, but I don't know how can I distinguish them. When I right click on Files and Folders, the program must distinguish them.

[image: Different menus]

My code in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Margin="140,70,0,0">
        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="-140,-68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36">
            <MenuItem Background="#FF877E7E" Foreground="Black" Header="File" Height="24" Width="36">
                <MenuItem x:Name="open" Header="Open" Click="open_Click"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="exitBtn" Header="Exit" Click="exitBtn_Click_1"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TreeView Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="318" Margin="-99,-68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309">
            <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="delete" Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="open1" Header="Open1" Click="Open_Click1"/>
                    <!--<MenuItem x:Name="create" Header="Create"Click=""-->
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeView.ContextMenu>
        </TreeView>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: There are different ways to do what you want, but first create a collection of viewmodels to bind to the TreeView's ItemsSource.  Create properties Name and IsDirectory in your ViewModel.  Use a DataTrigger to set your ContextMenu for each TreeViewItem which means you're also going to need an ItemTemplate.

Comment: how can i make a collection of them? im not good in xaml and im searching but cant find anything good. Because the size must be uknown

Comment: We don't see how you populate the tree-view. It seems that you're not using any MVVM concepts. Maybe you should start with that and first learn what is MVVM and how to use it with WPF. Then, you can easily answer your question by yourself.

Comment: For example, you should have classes called `TreeViewViewmodel` and `TreeViewItemViewModel`. `TreeViewItemViewModel` could have the following Properties: `Name` and `IsDirectory`.  `TreeViewViewModel` could then have a Property called `Items` of type `ObservableCollection<TreeViewItemViewModel>`